# Jest Mock react-navigation HOC withNavigationFocus

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, enzyme

I create a react component and use the following export

```
export default withNavigationFocus(AddTicket);
```

I create the following in `__mocks_/react-navigation.js` (with automock setup)

```
export function withNavigationFocus(component) {
  return component;
}
```

When testing the component using `expect(wrapper.find(SafeAreaView).length).toEqual(1);` I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Enzyme::Selector expects a string, object, or Component Constructor
```

When logging the component object in function withNavigationFocus I get

```
{ [Function: AddTicket]
      propTypes:
       { active_truck_id: [Function: bound checkType],
         editActiveLoad: [Function: bound checkType],
         isFocused: [Function: bound checkType],
         navigation: [Function: bound checkType] },
      navigationOptions: { title: 'Add Ticket', tabBarVisible: false } }
```

To the best of my understanding, this mock withNavigationFocus and simply returning the react component.

```
What is your question?
```

How do I allow these tests to pass?

Comment: withNavigationFocus can be found at https://github.com/react-navigation/core/blob/master/src/views/withNavigationFocus.js

Comment: what is your question?